# Xslt to convert Japanese time output to English time

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list where the date time is stored as "平成 27/7/14" and when i wirte an xsl for the date column to render using the line

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(concat(substring(string(@PeriodFrom),4,3),substring(string(@PeriodFrom),1,3),substring(string(@PeriodFrom),7,4)),1033,'yyyy/MM/dd')"></xsl:value-of>**
```

I receive a blank output. Request to help me on this regard

Comment: What is the expected result here? Is it - as I would assume -  `2015-07-14` or is it something else? And what does the `ddwrt:FormatDateTime()` function expect as its input? Can it even handle imperial dates? Currently, your calculation feeds it `27/平成 7/14` which makes no sense.

Comment: The output expected is "2015/07/14", but i get the result as blank as i am unable to convert the japanese time to UTC i guess

Comment: I am not a SharePoint user. I suspect the function expects a Gregorian date in ISO-8601 format as its input - which is also what you want as the output, so it will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT 1.0 template will convert a Japanese imperial date to Gregorian and output it as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
<xsl:template name="imperial-to-gregorian">
    <xsl:param name="imperial-date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="era" select="substring-before($imperial-date, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-after($imperial-date, ' ')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="imperial-year" select="substring-before($date, '/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="offset">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$era='平成'">1988</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$era='昭和'">1925</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$era='大正'">1911</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$era='明治'">1867</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$era='慶応'">1864</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="$imperial-year + $offset"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($year, '0000')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($month, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($day, '-00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Example of call:

```
<start>
  <xsl:call-template name="imperial-to-gregorian">
      <xsl:with-param name="imperial-date" select="@PeriodFrom"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</start>
```

Result when `PeriodFrom ="平成 27/7/14"`:

```
<start>2015-07-14</start>
```